# Sql server 2000 remote connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, connection

Hi i want to know how to enable remote server connection in sql server 2000. I have sql server 2000 installed in a system with windows server 2003 os. i want to create a dsn connection to the database through remote. I have created a dsn locally in the server it is working. but how to create dsn from the remote system and make it work.

Answer (score 1):

To allow remote connections to the server, do the following:

In SQL Server Enterprise Manager, right-click the server and choose **Properties**.
On the **General** tab, click the **Network Configuration** button and enable *Named Pipes*, and *TCP/IP* in the new window. I'm not sure if you need to restart SQL Server after doing this.

After doing this, you should be able to connect to the SQL Server from a remote computer, by referring to e.g. MYSERVER\MyInstanceName.

Comment: Connections to SQL Server are typically established through port 1433, unless you have changed this. Is there anything blocking access to the server, such as a firewall?

Comment: I should probably also ask if you have tried connecting and it failed, or if you simply don't know how to setup the connection?

Answer (score 0):

It helped me.

BTW I've also added sqlservr.exe to my firewall exception list:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841251

Answer (score 0):

Try installing MSDE/connectivity tools on remote system.